# Style a button to maintain its highlighting after leaving the page and returning

Tags: html, css

When a link is clicked and the browser redirects to another page the highlighting is maintained when revisiting the original page. This allows the user to know which links she has clicked even after they have left the page. Is it possible to apply this same functionality to a button?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. But it depends on what framework you are using, how your HTML and CSS look like, etc.

Comment: well the best way I can think of is a use of cookies

Comment: why would the framework I'm using make a difference? I'd like to see a solution with Html and Css. Maybe Javascript/jQuery.